# List of Italian proper names and common diminutives

Tags: regional, proper-nouns, synonym, list

I was wondering whether there is a Wikipedia page holding a complete list of Italian proper names, and their diminutives (for example, Francesco: Checco, Giuliano: Nano, etc.). Not sure if names can have more than one diminutive, or whether these diminutives are also subject to regional variation.

I'm also not sure whether regional variants can be properly called diminutives, or whether they are just variations in themselves, in which case I would imagine that there could be quite a lot of them, although I wouldn't count it. So, if a page existed with all these peculiarities, perhaps even listing the region and city where the diminutive was used, with users perhaps also contributing, I think that could be cool.

As an aside, I realize that there may even be popular diminutive which mothers use, either publicly or privately, and I'm not sure whether these would count as standard in Italian as well or not, just wondering (could be a questioning issue).

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding this (and also your other question about proper nouns) you may find some books (for instance [La Stella's one](https://www.zanichelli.it/ricerca/prodotti/dizionario-dei-nomi-di-persona)), while most websites tend to be quite amateurish.

Comment: @DaG I think that could be the base for a great answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed such Wiktionary pages, though they are not exhaustive and do not contain much further information:

- [Wiktionary: Italian male given names](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Italian_male_given_names) (830)
- [Wiktionary: Italian diminutives of male given names](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Italian_diminutives_of_male_given_names) (29)

- [Wiktionary: Italian female given names](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Italian_female_given_names) (285)
- [Wiktionary: Italian diminutives of female given names](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Italian_diminutives_of_female_given_names) (6)

The English Wikipedia pages for most given names contain a section called 'In other languages' which often lists the Italian cognate form if it exists:

e.g. [Wikipedia: John (given name) - In other languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_(given_name)#In_other_languages)

Answer (score 5):

You can find here a [list of Italian proper names](https://www.culturaesvago.com/etimologia-nomi-e-modi-di-dire/nomi-di-persona-a-b/) (in Italian) where you can find some information about etymology and meaning.

Many of them come form history, literature, or from philosophers, scientist of ancient times.

For some of them is also reported if they are diminutives of a longer form, for example:

> - **TEA** - Diminutivo di molti nomi femminili, tra cui **Dorotea**, **Teodora**, **Teofila** ecc.
> - **TIM** - È il diminutivo di **TIMOTEO**.
> - **TONY/TONIO** - Diminutivo di **ANTONIO**
> - **TURI** - Accorciativo di **Salvatore**, è ormai usato come nome proprio.

If you need more information about particular and popular diminutives and in which region they are used, I would suggest to look into regional dictionaries.

On Treccani you can find valuable resources about propers name, like [*Le tipologie dei nomi personali del Novecento in Italia*](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/speciali/nomi/papa.html).

Moreover, regarding books and studies about names, I can mention [*I nomi di persona in Italia: dizionario storico ed etimologico*](https://iris.unito.it/handle/2318/99522?mode=full.1561) by A. Rossebastiano e E. Papa, Utet, (2005).

Comment: I don't think that “Tim” and “Tony” are *Italian* diminutives. There is “Toni” (or “’Ntoni”), but writing it “Tony” seems a provincialism.